# How to install Android voip by using jingle with webrtc?

Tags: android, voip, webrtc

I have installed gclient and get jingle code.

I followed this link(https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client)

- tools/badit_android.py --->success
- second step mvn install was stoped after this line.was this ending? still have any?

  ```
  [INFO] /home/liv/VOIP/VOIP-android/android-ndk-r8d-lin/ndk-build [-C, /home/liv/VOIP/VOIP-android/kumar/trunk/android/voice-client-native, NDK_APPLICATION_MK=jni/default_debug.mk, -j, 2, NDK_APP_OUT=/home/liv/VOIP/VOIP-android/kumar/trunk/android/voice-client-native/obj/default_debug, all]
  ```
- run this command:

  ```
  build/android/gdb_apk -p com.tuenti.voice.example -s VoiceClientService -l android/voice-client-native/obj/${build_profile}/local/${app_abi}
  ```

  got error message:

  > Debug package com.tuenti.voice.example
  >   Assume native shared library is under android/voice-client-native/obj//local/
  >   No com.tuenti.voice.example running?
  >   Try this: adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW  -n com.tuenti.voice.example/.SomethingActivity (Something might be ContentShell)

*)run try this command got error this error:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.liv.network/.LoginActivity }

really i dont know what will i do for run this project? really this readme file is very difficult to see and run.

what is the procedure for xmpp jingle voip enable for my project.why i do this step? i dont know get the reason.Please help me

send the link for any sample project using jinglelib for voip

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0NU-E8l_qQ 
I am also trying it out, but get stuck after building successfully and then fail to find the 'libs' folder/directory.

Comment: I've also tried this link and failed to find 'libs' folder.